# Salesforce Connect report limitations?

Tags: analytics, lightning-connect, externalobjects

We have an Odata endpoint configured for SF Connect access.  3 simple external objects, and having an extremely difficult time getting reports to function.
Standard reports are ok until you add any filter (to filter down below the 2000 row limit), then I get a

> The Query is too complex

The filter added was to filter one date field down to greater than `01/01/2018`.
So decided to use Analytics Studio to do this.  I can connect to the objects, see data, but when I attempt to sync the object:

> Object InvoiceHeader__x is not supported
>   02K0z000000D8Z9EAK_03C0z00000055BJEAY)

Is anyone else having this issue?  Does anyone USE Salesforce Connect? Any help is greatly appreciated!!!